# Is it appropriate to use Oauth2 only for first-party clients?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I've been reading a lot about Oauth2 authorization but I can't seem to find a definitive answer to my question, so I was hoping one of you could help me out here.

If I understand correctly, Oauth2 has been designed specifically for authorizing parts of your API to public third-party clients. I can't seem to find any mention in the spec about authorizing first-party clients. I've read some articles about using the implicit grant type, but it feels like using the implicit grant type for this purpose, is not really what the spec was designed for.

Let's assume I have an API which I would like to access through a web application and a native mobile application. Users can create accounts on these applications and access certain parts of the API. I also want to have a admin portal which can access all parts of the API. So I need some kind of authorization in my API, but since all these applications are first-party client (made by me), it feels wrong to use Oauth2 here.

Hence my question, is it appropriate to use Oauth2 for first-party applications and if not, what could be an alternative for authorization of first-party clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 is used for service-to-service Authorization.

When user Authentication is involved, OpenID Connect is the proper choice.

You can utilize the "[prompt parameter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Prompt%20Parameter)" in OpenID Connect [Authentication Request](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) is an OPTIONAL Space-delimited, case-sensitive list of ASCII string values that specifies whether the Authorization Server prompts the Resource Owner for re-authentication and consent.

Generally, using the value "none" then the Authorization Server MUST NOT display any authentication or consent user interface pages.

Comment: Thanks for replying! OpenID is build on top of Oauth, right? Would it still be the right choice for first-party clients, since Oauth was originally meant for third-party clients, as stated in the other answer?

Comment: I see no reasons not to use OAuth/OIDC under those conditions and this is how OIDC is used many Organization and implemented in commercial products.

Answer (score 4):

The original goal of OAuth was to allow third party apps to access an API on your behalf without giving them your credentials.

Now, if you own all actors (client, authorization server and resource server), the user will submit their credentials to something you own (the authorization server when logging in).

The other thing is that the consent screen may be of less value since the client is made by the same company that already manages your resources. The user may still want to reduce the permissions of certain clients (for example, only allow your mobile client to read your bank transactions, while the web client may create new transactions).

Having said that, OAuth2 is still a good protocol for any client to obtain access tokens for an API. You can use off-the-shelf libraries to implement it in your applications and services and avoid implementing your own authentication system.

Using OAuth2 for your APIs will give you the possibility to easily allow third party clients later on.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Wouldn’t it be strange though, to show the user a “permisssions” screen in, for example, the admin panel?

Comment: It depends. The consent screen is really to let the user delegate permissions to the client app. For first party apps, you could skip it all together, or implement something like a role based authorization model, where someone else determines what role the user is in and thus what the user is allowed to do.